# NSPredicate with a !=?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have Core Data Entities Person and Boundary. They have a many-to-many relationship (each person can have many boundaries, and each boundary can have many persons).

I am trying to create a list of what boundaries Person Fred doesn't have a relationship too.

```
Person *person = [Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"name" withValue:@"Fred"];
DLog(@"person.boundaries.count: %d", person.boundaries.count);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY persons != %@", person];

DLog(@"testBoundaries.count: %d", [Boundary MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:predicate]);
```

I have 47 boundaries in the database, and Fred can see all 47. So I expect my fetch to return 0:

```
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | person.boundaries.count: 47
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | testBoundaries.count: 47
```

What is wrong with my predicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY persons != %@", fred]
```

finds all objects that are related to any person other that Fred. What you want is

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(ANY persons = %@)", fred]
```

and this *should* return all objects that are not related to Fred.

**However**, there seems to be a Core Data bug that "NOT ANY" or "NONE" do not work correctly
in a predicate,
compare [NSPredicate Aggregate Operations with NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471910/nspredicate-aggregate-operations-with-none). The workaround is to use a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(persons, $p, $p == %@).@count == 0", fred]
```

Comment: Actually I did not yet test if the Bug has been fixed in iOS 7, so "NOT ANY" might be worth a try ...

Comment: This did it! The subquery worked. Thank you again Martin! Man, I wish I could buy you a beer for all the times you've helped me out.

Comment: No. the `NOT ANY` would return 46 boundaries for some odd reason.

Comment: When using fred + another person, this doesn't work. So fred + sally returns all that do not include fred or sally AND any records that include just fred + sally. @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR as we discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47001325/1951992 changing to 'in' does the trick in this case. [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(persons, $p, $p in %@).@count == 0", [fred, sally]]

Comment: @robdashnash: Here OP asked for all objects which are not related to a given (single) person "Fred".

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask first in `Class Boundary` if there is a person called Fred that has boundaries. It should be something like:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Boundary"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY persons.name != %@", person.name];
```

That will fetch all the boundaries that Fred doesn't have.